Running dotMemory in PowerShell results in “Unable to attach to the process”
I'm trying to automate running dotMemory.exe from commandline to analyze multiple processes. I use the dotMemory standalone commandline version.
I now run into an issue what sometimes occurs.
dotMemory.exe fails with a "“Unable to attach to the process #mynumber: Make sure it exists and it is a .NET Framework 4.0+/.NET Core 3.0+/.NET 5+ process.”"
If I start a new PowerShell instance, it works fine, but the original PowerShell instance cannot be used anymore. Does not matter how many times to run. I have to close the powershell window and open an new window and it works again.
Command that I use: .\dotMemory-2024.1.1.exe --log-level=trace attach 14768
(14768 is the PID)
I also tried it in a powershell script but that resulted in the same issue.
$proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process

$proc.StartInfo.FileName = "dotMemory-2024.1.1.exe"
$proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "--log-level=trace attach 14768"
$proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$proc.Start()

What I found in %Temp%\2\JetLogs\JetBrainsLog.JetBrains.2024-04-23T12-20-58.dotMemory-2024_1_1#14768.log
--- EXCEPTION #1/2 [FileLoadException]
Message = “Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)”
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = System.IO.FileLoadException
HResult = FUSION_E_REF_DEF_MISMATCH=80131040
Source = System.Memory
FileLoad_FileName = “System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”
FileLoad_FusionLog = “
  === Pre-bind state information ===
  LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
   (Fully-specified)
  LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/someuser/AppData/Local/Temp/2/JetBrains/dotMemory.exe/Qudorinirexidelu
  LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
  Calling assembly : System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
  ===
  LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
  LOG: No application configuration file found.
  LOG: Using host configuration file: 
  LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
  LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
  LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/someuser/AppData/Local/Temp/2/JetBrains/dotMemory.exe/Qudorinirexidelu/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.DLL.
  WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
  ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

What I see in the log is the 'Framework64\v4.0.30319'. I know dotMemory requires 4.7.2. Is it somehow using a wrong .NET version?

Have you restarted your application as well or you attach dotMemory to same instance?
Anyway, first try to reinstall .NET Framework 4.7.2 on your machine.

@EdPavlov Same instance, but if I start dotMemory from another powershell shell it works. I'll try to reinstall 472.

Please use reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\full" /v version to detect .NET Framework v4 version

@MikhailPilin It reported 4.7.03062 (which is 4.7.2) and is installed via a Windows Update. I found the real issue: rights. The application runs as a service  and required dotMemory to run as admin.

I found the real issue. The application is running as a service. It required to run dotMemory as administrator to attach.

Why then does it work on the first launch?
